# The scitype of X in Machine is incompatible with model

Tags: julia

I am trying to use MLJ to train some data using the random forest classifier. In order to do that, I have `coerce` my categorical variables to `Multiclass`(scitype) and continuous features to `Continuous`. (I have also changed the target variables scitype to `Multiclass`)

```
 MLJ.schema(X)
```

[image]

However when I construct the machine object I get the following warning,

```
 mach = machine(forest, X,y)

 ┌ Warning: The scitype of `X`, in `machine(model, X, ...)` is incompatible 
 with `model=RandomForestClassifier @695`:
 │ scitype(X) = Table{Union{AbstractArray{Continuous,1}, 
 AbstractArray{Multiclass{8},1}, AbstractArray{Multiclass{3},1}, 
 AbstractArray{Multiclass{14},1}, AbstractArray{Multiclass{7},1}, 
 AbstractArray{Multiclass{12},1}}}
 │ input_scitype(model) = Table{var"#s45"} where var"#s45" 
 <:Union{AbstractArray{var"#s13",1} where var"#s13"<:Count, 
 AbstractArray{var"#s13",1} where var"#s13"<:OrderedFactor, 
 AbstractArray{var"#s13",1} where var"#s13"<:Continuous}.
```

followed by this `TaskFailedExceptionError`when I fit the model

```
trainRows, testRows = partition(eachindex(y),0.7, shuffle = true)
MLJ.fit(mach, rows = trainRows)
```

I tested the model with just the Continuous features and it works fine. So it's something incorrect with categorical variables (with scitype `Muticlass`), but can't quite figure out what it is. Any ideas what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

The [MLJDecisionTreeInterface](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/MLJDecisionTreeInterface.jl) does not support the `Multiclass` scitype. [GitHub:](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/MLJDecisionTreeInterface.jl/blob/c591d26e02464fb97cfe112dde321e735d498fff/src/MLJDecisionTreeInterface.jl#L32)

```
Inputs are tables with ordinal columns. That is, the element scitype
of each column can be `Continuous`, `Count` or `OrderedFactor`.
```

One possible solution would be to expand out the categorical columns of the table as one-hot encoded columns like in [this forum post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/encoding-categorical-variables-within-a-matrix/32628).